# Does $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{3n-2}{n+1}\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think that there could be used Abel and Dirichlet method, but I have no idea how

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{3n-2}{n+1}\frac{1}{n^{1/2}} .$$

Comment: yes, by leibniz criterion.

Comment: Is this series decreasing? If so what test can you use?

Comment: But it isn't decreasing, Does that mean that this serie diverges?

Comment: $(3n-2)/((n+1)\sqrt n)$ will be decreasing after a certain point in the sequence; that's good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Write the fraction as
$3-5/(n+1)$.

The sum of the first converges by Leibnitz
and the second converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

The series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}}$$
is convergent by Leibniz. The difference from the original series
is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{3n-2}{(n+1) n^{1/2}}-\frac{3}{n^{1/2}}\right)$$
which is aboslutely convergent, since the terms are $O(n^{-3/2})$.